# nodejs server shows starting up but never starts

Tags: node.js, backend, nodemon

I just started learning nodejs and there is some weird error coming when I try to run `nodemon server.js` command.

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Hello World");
});

server.listen(3030);
```

My VScode terminal shows this but the server never starts.

[image: VsCode terminal]

Here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "video-chat-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "peer": "^0.6.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.1.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you know it doesnt start?

Comment: Have you tried hitting the server endpoint? It may actually be running, I dont see a callback in the call to listen to print anything let you know.

Comment: Yes it shows the site can't be reached. I guess it should be a blank page if server was running

Comment: I am afraid its not a reproducible issue. This code should work as everyone would agree on. It must be specific to your environment and hence It's not generally reproducible. I literally copied the content of your files into this repl, and it works. https://replit.com/@bluebrown/express-test

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `http`, express is already enough to start a server.

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Hello World");
});

app.listen(3030, ()=>{
  console.log('Server is starting');
});
```

Comment: But I think it should work the other way too